# AWS EC2 Default Ruby Version on Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rbenv

so I have my rails project hosted with AWS EC2 using the amazon linux server. by default, `ruby -v` returns ruby 2.0 but my project was designed on 2.3.3 (latest at the time). in order for me to change the ruby version using `rbenv` i have to run the following every time i log in via ssh

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init
$ source ~/.bash_profile
$ eval "$(rbenv init -)"
$ type rbenv
```

since i have the global ruby version in rbenv set as 2.3.3 already.
then i can run

```
$ ruby -v
#returns 2.3.3
$ rails s
#or any other rails commands
```

is there any way I can set it so I don't have to edit the .bash_profile every time?

what I get if I run the above code, then exit the ssh, and ssh back in

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
$ rbenv global
2.3.3
$ rbenv local
2.3.3
$ rails s
-bash: rails: command not found
##### run above code and nothing else #####
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-linux]
$ rails s
# starts rails server without issue
```

Answer (score 3):

It should work without your ritual after every log in. I believe you don't quite understand what's going on there. Let's start it line by line.

```
# add init of rbenv on every login to the file .bash_profile to make available rbenv CLI
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
# call rbenv native initializer for first time only (it shows you what else you could do for rbenv)
$ ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv init
# read and execute .bash_profile (string in echo in the first cmd)
$ source ~/.bash_profile
# as far I remember it isn't used anymore
$ eval "$(rbenv init -)"
# this is just a smoke test to check if rbenv works 
$ type rbenv
```

Once you completed it, you don't need to do it on the next logins, because it should be run automatically. If this doesn't work you could try to replace `.bash_profile` to `.bashrc` in the commands above.

In order to fix the version of ruby use this [reference](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version)

Comment: I knew you were only supposed to run the code once, so having to run it everytime didn't make sense to me.<br>I changed to .bashrc but I still get `-bash: rails: command not found` when running `rails c` if I re-run all of the above code, I can then run `rails c`

Comment: Could you add `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` content as well? You may use github gists so as not to inflate the question.